# Waterfall chart with subtotals

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I need to create a [waterfall](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/waterfall_chart.html) chart with vega but I need to have subtotals. For this subtotals the next bars keep showing as expected but starting at the subtotal quantity.

This is feasible with excel and Tableau but I didn't manage to do it with Vega.

I need to create something like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEGor.png)

Any idea if the vega waterfall chart allows this functionality

Comment: This is definitely possible but you'll need to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of Vega waterfall chart with "subtotals" bars the way you described.

There is a waterfall chart in Vega-Lite gallery (but not in Vega), so we start off with using the Vega version that is generated by Vega-Lite in the [on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/waterfall_chart).

The first step is to add records to the input data for where the subtotals will appear. In this example, we added *"Qtr_1"*, *"Qtr_2"* and *"Qtr_3"* to represent quarterly subtotals:

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "source_0",
      "values": [
        {"label": "Begin", "amount": 4000},
        {"label": "Jan", "amount": 1707},
        {"label": "Feb", "amount": -1425},
        {"label": "Mar", "amount": -1030},

        {"label": "Qtr_1", "amount": 0},

        {"label": "Apr", "amount": 1812},
        {"label": "May", "amount": -1067},
        {"label": "Jun", "amount": -1481},

        {"label": "Qtr_2", "amount": 0},

        {"label": "Jul", "amount": 1228},
        {"label": "Aug", "amount": 1176},
        {"label": "Sep", "amount": 1146},

        {"label": "Qtr_3", "amount": 0},
        
        {"label": "Oct", "amount": 1205},
        {"label": "Nov", "amount": -1388},
        {"label": "Dec", "amount": 1492},
        {"label": "End", "amount": 0}
      ]
    },
```

Note that there are existing bars for "Begin" and "End". We can modify the code referencing these bars to render bars for quarterly subtotals.

For example, code such as

```
"fill": [
     {
        "test": "datum.label === 'Begin' || datum.label === 'End',
        "value": "#725a30"
     },
```

has been changed to:

```
"fill": [
     {
        "test": "datum.label === 'Begin' || datum.label === 'End' || substring(datum.label, 0, 4) === 'Qtr_'",
         "value": "#725a30"
     },
```

Often code has been changed to use signal expressions for greater flexibility. For example,

```
"y": {"scale": "y", "field": "previous_sum"},
```

has been changed to

```
"y": {"signal": "scale('y', substring(datum.label, 0, 4) === 'Qtr_' ? 0 : datum['previous_sum'])"},
```

Here is the result [waterfall chart rendered on the Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBMkUANZkATmwbiAJmhAB3GHTjSQOJBo01xZNAJk6aG+mgAcABhcz4NMljQAWAe4gEJgAngA2huhQcGFhRhpImCioANqg4kgIkUFqytEA+i5GxEhhDHAQaGkgYUhMMdoAQuQWRplq4ph+bi4AvlKgtfVx6ABSSJIy7epdqACMAOwuC-2DdQ3oAGJwTG0IHbMAtHO+AEwCqzXrIyAAskjKewdoxy4AzH0DV8PaAIqYynycyeMzQnzWP3QAEEcI8pvtQfMnHNTpchhs7kgQiDOi85i4AGwrL7om6jdQ4o4nZFo65-AH5U6UsG0yEgclxeHPeanU5OVkYqEMKxcxFzRYEgU3ADKcBwzPmJ0lJLp6H+gLeCvB3wxAHkoF1RbieS4Liq2QA5NjEBXHN5OfnmjEAETgUAVJwAnKinTcAKKaLW9AC6lwyWW0CSShSMYgYeWycYTMZkAImEAAZmxlAgqqBQjhsnZNGwdEYTMpMpVUuIGLFg1Nqykggxcw2QGw8FUW22ZBmaDENE2QNNce2xMpZqB+4Oqu3sxo4I9UqHLgWixYNKXyw8q1Va-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-r8uh6b5thlbzN05qMhJo7HXO2z6bu6k+a80B3s-m1xmixLYRS7HPb5OTYfJRHEBa+IOt6yRIetrX4hQGHidU8nTt074DMO9b2fVeznM5h7hdewLJfC2X-uV4H1ew-D9ca03UdwDH7dx53G8JyGScRoP+QCCPCYpymE+51z+c83Rb7F0LX3aOXAdBwbT2C5vjfN1btXX+S5e4n3bMgZQCgmyWzPlcEIS5Cj5EgdAl2s8QAqQNLGUIERuxyEeLeVQuZUCgFpjfYE-RPrdzYIuNAoAGA4CjJEac-MRjVBqsEZm+FzIbR4n1cKiEhojR4WNaygjJrMBmnNIOXUYjLXcIhNaPVNoMihjIEoZRsgAGIMwLDgC4JgBIaKNQqLMLOEk-oAxxtdZWxRSjlG0DohYTgkAEmHpcDRDj0BaM9G8KAvgkAoBDFMWaSAABKbAIiumgLNHAmB2CSBISATx2R8HGJMhUKAsT4kSDoUELwGQbjy1JEReWZVEK+U-ivb+xTrj1zBidA2pJVaiXlvLNujTanDHruVeWABuRCUIESdFKSAcpvkGKJBqYbGx8cGyITaSAYqpVekgAGdpUZ4zJmYGmXM5aizlnpIgu6JJ0BSjZAgkYd82hSRGDkIGVALhKBml0PYRwSSUl+BediU5BTSgwygOc3yPEQg8WWlNKRlgZFLRWoo9alkto7REkRfWPFAazNbDxNW6SQhMlOYC3B6BsR9gHPeGGrYaJ-lPtkWoCDARzGQQ8VBqZ0HKDrIYdOODIjNjZbgwhbBiGkJtjfJklC4DUNoUkhhTC8mdnkHQH5oBPnzEoTNNgCg4AAHU3kwDycqn0QQATquYck+x2jfAuAtRa9Ji4Yk0DiQkvJEA-lFJ1GETZ5VKnLyrvvN19SYpNLqWeVpIB2nV2aabcp-TEIbIWWMz12zdmtlVvs0NSyVlxoGQhD1FSqk+s6VeUw-rw3kRaaMsNvqEJgJkJc-F5ztCXJJbOKidIvwZgzBAOARxeTPJkPcj8TyXkQTxaAM5hKQCNpfs2wtFEOzts7bMHtNhZATAHc8yhiqggEuyMSqdZLSYUqpdSm5WJEGnEZVAyoLLn41QggpYI4RuXVVqmePsRC8lkPPpqMVEqTXSsSCauQnbK7iBNcq2QbBsACptZu5VhxfCUP7LEPVZrHFWstUUShtqsn2pyYk0dLrtBdJiDmr1Fd80y2I2EYtlag3BhDRWgtEa1ZRrWTGzu5NSOJrXhx7uKa43y0OZQ2to7t0NquaSj8bq7mrrBOumQm6x07ok9Osm3d0m3tfM6sghSP7etXr6tTPdI0NMozXOuwby0gA6WZozqt0mSx0yhzR2gQGPCPf3OBtLEFvAvcyp+2RNPYMfd2IL-LBVZ2SJF-I7jwK-ryf+mqeSgMxAsGB1D6BMCdhg85rxCGSXIY+RlkAWj0PWqw5k7Jjrfk6f+egKjpG80GaY3R0qpng5UbLQJ6z4bWusfWYfN0XGPJTJ4wgOGbp+MHLNsJp1Yn0CTuuS2n4fbZOPPkyART83Nsqf3TXeGGmX01d0+gJrSbxtHxY+1juF3JuWe6zZjr+27vBgc5XJzRWXNRHFT7DzsCaWnsBL4PzV6AvaCC5ykLl4wtvug0kz90XL4-qgDQv9jCAPJaQMBtLuXsgIHsBoXBiGJCYE1XALwPhPteIg2SxDrCPamK4bFbqvD+ETWESz0RSUhEQoBNIgK1x5GrXhQlRFdivuyBcx44regDDmxkNhqruTjt1bTSUuN4yzu9e6SZgNnX7uLMe4GnXLHVkDLc8NnMo3fVuam2m5Z-XEKafqsMzAjX9PTOd-JGjBaveu664b6ufuDjVonXN+tC3dtSduath5g6N3h-HbupbIA3OHbvU6wjB7pp86hQL4YQu4XKJ4oioSKR89yN4ocMFhMED0aIlr31weZg+7M83zoAe01G-lu3zA9nKGOfw6aiXaej3jm3TAkA1NxPXtSbJhXAqkCtCSe+SfCPab0ybXt25lx1820ZFHk9Pxd-CvPnbFP1ET9JBvmnPd0e6RX6ixv4eW-7-H6+Hv6Ml9X9H4aCfGQ7MZA3K7gBGtWNwdgDguqwSxgpg5glgAAkuIKBsuE8nMDICYGYHNLqAwD7OtqaMekSmgs-CBteELFuMgMviwoOGvqftFsCD-ugOikrNpMYkKtfufPQXfuSjpB-rQRvufpJtwawZFjfofgeuNuTMIZ-kPGIc9gjLwewYjrIaPpTBghMEAdzNpidhgOTt4F0P0C4O2C3I7ACOUDIAAF5LhsBoCmFwDQFIAQQVCaHba7rZgDjGhXgZgKQqD2DSjbaTo+Efi2Gpg0CKAADC3IoB2h0Q-MvkngehBAFqM2C+FBiSGYpQnaMgpI1Y6RYQmRI4oSaAuR+RyAEEfod6P2YIMg+O4g5RNUxogQ8SigORGRcAFhm4kELIXwSmM+HYs0lR6ATAkGWWuYMggRRRrRIRmA46twJOMAoOpIUIlghKgQpIjQWOqWoG4O2W7RmgnRjylwPRhBX4-RHhEQXhRg4xqAxRbR1UdA46QyzwWR1wuopAygtQ8oqAwRdx4RkR+SYBrm5OYQcRuhWAiRLgyRIA5hHRtafQ7YKO4g-YVgpyXKeSQWK+JOZOFOZiQxtOVKQAA). To find code changes, search for "Qtr_" in the code.

[image]